# Angular reactive form not submitting selected option values

Tags: arrays, angular, html-select, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following form dinamically populated with multiple select inputs

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchForm.value)">
   <div class="col-md-2" *ngFor="let filter of this.filters; index as i">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select formArrayName="filters" size="5" class="form-control" (change)="onSelectChange($event)">
          <option [ngValue]="null" value="-1" disabled class="first-option-item">{{ filter.name }}</option>
          <option
            *ngFor="let filterValue of this.filterValues[i].items"
            [ngValue]="filterValue">
              {{ filterValue.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Reactive form init:

```
this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  searchString: ['', Validators.required],
  filters: this.formBuilder.array([ ])
});
```

However I don't have any values on the filter array when I submit the form

[image]

Furthermore, when I log `e.target.value` on my (change) method I only get the selected option value. I want to access the full object i.e `{ id: 1, name: 'first_filter' }`. Don't I need the full object so I can return it somehow to the FormGroup?

Comment: Can you show how the filters are being added

Comment: this.preferencesService.getAllFilters().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.filters = res.filters;
      this.filterValues = res.filter_items;})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your problem

You are building an array of selects in a form. When you submit the form, the select values aren't set.

#### The design

When binding to form arrays, you bind the array to `formArrayName`, and each control in the array to `[formControlName]="i"`.

#### The solution

Move `formArrayName="filters"` to a higher level, and add `[formControlName]="i"` to the select. This will bind the `i`th select to the `i`th control in the form array.

I've also amended your `[ngValue]="filterValue"` to use `filterValue.name` for the purposes of my example.

```html
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="col-md-2" *ngFor="let filter of this.filters; index as i"
    formArrayName="filters">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select [formControlName]="i" size="5" class="form-control" (change)="onSelectChange($event)">
        <option [ngValue]="null" value="-1" disabled class="first-option-item">{{ filter.name }}</option>
        <option
          *ngFor="let filterValue of this.filterValues[i].items"
          [ngValue]="filterValue.name">
            {{ filterValue.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i3njdo

Comment: My list of filters is loaded from an external server so when I push an empty formBuilder control into filtersFormArray, I get the error Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. I want the submitted object to contain all the input fields plus an array of selected filters. Is this approach helping me to achieve this?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with how you're building your form rather than how you're binding to it. If you're building you're form based on one set of requests, I would recommend waiting until the responses come back before building your forms. I've updated my stackblitz to mock this up. Note - this isn't a complete solution - I'm just demonstrating the techniques you use.

Comment: I tried to setup the formBuilder group after I receive the response but I get an error saying 'SearchComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.'

Comment: Notice I added `*ngIf="searchForm"` to my stackblitz. You can only bind to the form group after it's been created

Comment: Thanks! It works indeed. Is it possible to get only the selected option value object when submitting the data? Currently I  get all the options, regardless the selected state. I think it has to do  with `this.filtersFormArray = this.formBuilder.array(this.filters);` before initializing formBuilder?

Comment: You can access the current values at any time you want. I demoed `(submit)` because that's a natural place to read values in a form, but there's nothing to stop you reading your form state at any given time.

Comment: I was trying to say that even though I'm not selecting anything, I get an array of options returned by this.filtersFormArray.controls.map(x => x.value)
Do you know if it's possible to only return an array of selected object if I actually select anything? Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208931/discussion-between-shakur-and-kurt-hamilton).